# Adding multiple images from a scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I need to select multiple images from a scroll view.

If I touch on that image, it shows a selection tick (check) mark; if I  touch it again, then it would be deselected.

Now I am doing like this:

I would like it so that when I click on that specific image it would show one tick (check) mark; if I touch on the second one, then it would show one tick (check) for this image, same as we select images from the camera roll.

So, please help me as quickly as possible.

The following is my code:

```
-(void)listimagesandanmae
{

int myFavV = [favCompcamelIDArr count];
for (int i = 0; i < myFavV; i++)
{
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * 100;


    favimageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin+20,10,70,70)];

    favimageView.layer.cornerRadius = favimageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    favimageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    //        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 60;
    //        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    favimageView.tag=i;

    NSInteger tag = favimageView.tag;
    // then do what you want with this

    if (([favCompcamelIDArr count] >0) ) {


    }

    favnamelistingLbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin+23,90,90,27)];

    favnamelistingLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    favnamelistingLbl.tag=i;


    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[favcompnsmeArr count]);

    if (([favCompcamelIDArr count] > 0) ) {

        favnamelistingLbl.text=[favcompnsmeArr objectAtIndex:i];

    }

    [_selectCamelFav addSubview:favnamelistingLbl];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tappedmyFav = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedmyFav:)];
    tappedmyFav.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [favimageView addGestureRecognizer:tappedmyFav];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)tag);

    NSString *urStCam=@"http://192.8.1.42:/da/";
    NSString *urStCam1=[urStCam stringByAppendingString:[favcompictureArr objectAtIndex:i]];

    NSString *urStCam2= [urStCam1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];


    [caArray addObject:urStCam2];
    NSLog(@"%@",caArray);

    NSURL *newUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:[caArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSData *imageDatash = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newUrl];
    UIImage *image123 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDatash scale:2.0];
    [favimageView setImage:image123];

    [_selectCamelFav addSubview:favimageView];
    favimageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


}
_selectCamelFav.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myFavV * 210, 171);

[_indicatorA startAnimating];
_indicatorA.hidden=YES;


 }

  - (void)tappedmyFav:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
 {
 UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) tap;

  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`. It'll be far easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subclass UIView. Then add UIImageView, UILabel (the check mark) and a property to control if the UIView is selected. Also add Tap gesture handler (selected = !selected when tapped)

To search which view are selected, search through your scroll view for the 'selected' UIView object. Or you can maintain your own list once is an object is 'selected/unselected' so that you don't need to search all the objects.